# How to disable Excel instance merging?

Tags: excel

The latest versions of Excel have a new feature where Excel ignores a request for a new session if it detects one already running.  I want to know how to stop this.

This Microsoft Support article suggests adding a registry setting

```
Computer\HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\DisableMergeInstance = 1
```

but this did not work for me.  Can others please test if it works for them and report?

In the meantime I have discovered that holding the ALT key down whilst launching new Excel instance throws a dialog box saying "Do you want to start a new instance of Excel? (Yes/No)", this is shown in this [Microsoft article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/06/03/opening-workbooks-by-running-separate-instances-of-excel/).  This is a good workaround for the time being but I would like the registry setting to work.

Comment: You can start excel with the /x parameter to open it as new instance.  *Excel.exe /x*

Comment: @Sebastian: cool.  Works for me.  Thanks.

Comment: I saw the same behaviour as you and the suddenly it was fixed, but after the latest update it is back to not working. Very frustrating that this can not be handled consistently over time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative path... if it's of use to you.

big fan of the blog btw!

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" (ByVal lpszIID As Long, IID As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function CoCreateInstance Lib "ole32" (rclsid As Any, ByVal pUnkOuter As Long, _
    ByVal dwClsContext As Long, riid As Any, ByVal ppv As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "kernel32" (pDst As Any, pSrc As Any, ByVal dlen As Long)

Private Const CLSID_EXCELAPP    As String = "{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" ' Excel COM object GUID.

Private Const IID_DISPATCH      As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" 'IDispatch Interface GUID.

Private Const IID_NULL          As String = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"


Private Type GUID
    data1                       As Long
    data2                       As Integer
    data3                       As Integer
    data4(7)                    As Byte
End Type



Private Const CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER   As Long = &H4

Private Const S_OK                  As Long = &H0
Private Const E_NOINTERFACE         As Long = &H80004002
Private Const REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG   As Long = &H80040154
Private Const CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION As Long = &H80040110
Private Const E_POINTER             As Long = &H80004003

Sub CreateNewExcelInstance()
    Dim ExcelClassID        As GUID
    Dim IID                 As GUID
    Dim ObjectPtr           As Long
    Dim ExcelIIDHandle      As Long

    ExcelIIDHandle = IIDFromString(StrPtr(CLSID_EXCELAPP), ExcelClassID)
    If ExcelIIDHandle <> 0 Then Exit Sub

    ExcelIIDHandle = IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_DISPATCH), IID)
    If ExcelIIDHandle <> 0 Then Exit Sub

    ExcelIIDHandle = CoCreateInstance(ExcelClassID, 0, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID, VarPtr(ObjectPtr))

    Debug.Print ExcelIIDHandle = S_OK

'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'
'    -> If you want the second instance to be visible:
'
'               Dim SecondExcelInstance as Object
'
'               RtlMoveMemory SecondExcelInstance, ObjectPtr, 4
'
'               SecondExcelInstance.Visible = True
'               SecondExcelInstance.Workbooks.Add
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  Thanks for kind words about the blog.

Comment: I've found it useful having a VBA alternative as it provides a low cost method to plug in some basic multithreaded or asynchronous behavior without having to to deploy any additional dlls

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but this is for the people that find this with a web search.

The registry key is not supposed to be in the Computer hive, it's supposed to be in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance